# How to compare an enum flag to a Dictionary key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I've got this enum flag:

```
[Flags()]
public enum Levels
{
    Beginner, Medium, Advanced, Master
}
```

I've got a property called Bank, where this is a `Dictionary<Levels, ...>` and Levels are the possible options that you can choose

Let's go to suppose that my first `KeyValuePair` contains the following `Key = Levels.Beginner | Levels.Medium | Levels. Advanced`. So the idea if I enter in the dictionary `Levels.Medium`, returns me the last object because Medium is a possible value.

```
public Worksheet LoadWorksheet(Levels level)
{
    Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet(this.Bank[level].Value, this.Bank[level].Key);
    return worksheet;
}
```

But unfortunatly, when I do this, throws me an error pointing that the key does not exist. How can I do to match the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I should point out that if:

```
Levels keyA = Levels.Beginner | Levels.Medium | Levels. Advanced;
Levels keyB = Levels.Medium;
```

then:

```
Debug.Assert(keyA.GetHashCode() != keyB.GetHashCode());
Debug.Assert(keyA != keyB);
```

When looking up values in the dictionary, the dictionary first uses the hash value of the key to determine the correct bucket, and then uses equality comparison to identify the right key in the bucket.

If the hash values are not equal then the key will not be found.  If the key values are not equal, then the value will not be found.

You can get all entries that have a key containing `Levels.Medium` by seeing if it's bit pattern is present in the key with the following LINQ expression:

```
var mediumEntries = Bank.Where(entry => 0 != ((int)entry.Key & (int)Levels.Medium));
```

Or, as @Ria pointed out, in .Net 4 you can use the HasFlags member:

```
var mediumEntries = Bank.Where(entry => entry.Key.HasFlag(Levels.Medium));
```

The good point was made in another answers (@dasblinkenlight, @Ria) that the values of your enumeration need to have non-overlapping bit patterns for this to work:

```
[Flags()]        
public enum Levels        
{        
    Beginner = 0x01, 
    Medium = 0x02, 
    Advanced = 0x04, 
    Master = 0x08
}
```

Comment: I understand, but in this scenario, how can I deal with the problem? At this case, keyB contains a value inside of A, so I'm trying to match that.. but I have no idea

Comment: @DarfZon I'm trying to come up with a sample.  What is the type of the KeyValuePair Value?

Comment: It's a List<T> where T is a custom class

Comment: I just wanted to add that since you are no longer looking up values directly by key, but rather using LINQ expressions to search over the `Dictionary` as if it were an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`, you're essentially missing out on most of the `Dictionary`'s performance improvements. You're NOT using the inner Hashtable's quick lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Define enumeration constants in powers of two, that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap:

```
[Flags]
public enum Levels
{
    Beginner = 1, 
    Medium = 2,
    Advanced = 4, 
    Master = 8
}
```

and you must define Dictionary Key as Integer: `Dictionary<int, ...>`. and cast to `int` when adding to dictionary:

```
Bank.Add((int) (Levels.Medium|Levels.Master), ...);
```

then compare Key to enum flags:

```
if ((this.Bank[level].Key & Levels.Advanced) == Levels.Advanced)
{
     // Do something
}
```

and if using .NET4 use `HasFlag`

```
if ( this.Bank[level].Key.HasFlag(Levels.Advanced) )
{
     // Do something
}
```

---

**Note**:

`Dictionary.Key` must be unique. else throws an `ArgumentException` when attempting to add a duplicate key. so that Flag enumeration is not suggested for `Dictionary.Key`. Try to store some where else.

Comment: Why does the key type have to be `int`?  Wouldn't that mean the OP would have to always cast the key value back to the enum type?  I think it is better to cast the enum value to int when doing bitwise operations.